# Apache Velocity error in Eclipse [Java, Eclipse Luna, Velocity 2.0, VelocityView, Tomcat 7]

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, velocity

I want to start by specifiyng that I'm 90% new to all that means Java, Eclipse, templating engines.

In my attempt to create a velocity template that will run as intended I used Eclipse Luna(EE), Tomcat 7, Apache Velocity1.7, Velocity Tools 2.0, VelocityToolsView 2.0

**PROBLEM** is that when I start Tomcat from Eclipse (basicaly runing the project if you may), and go to "localhost:8080/VelocityTemplateHomework4/index.vm" it just throws me an entire page with the error "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet"

[image: error]

In eclipse (EE) I have basicaly followed this **tutorial**:

http://thegeekhead.blogspot.ro/2009/06/how-to-configure-eclipse-tomact-55.html

I'll post my code anyway but please check the link too (maybe there is an issue there since it's kinda outdated)

SimpleServlet.java

```
package myPackage;

public class SimpleServlet {
    private String message = "Hello Damn World!!!";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String m) {
        message = m;
    }

    /** To test exception handling in templates. */
    public boolean whine() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<web-app>
    <!-- Define Velocity template compiler -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.velocity.toolbox</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map *.vm files to Velocity -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

toolbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<toolbox>
    <xhtml>true</xhtml>
    <tool>
        <key>serv</key>
        <scope>request</scope>
        <request-path>index.vm</request-path>
        <class>SimpleServlet</class>
    </tool>
    <data type="number">
        <key>version</key>
        <value>1.1</value>
    </data>
    <data type="boolean">
        <key>isSimple</key>
        <value>true</value>
    </data>
    <data type="string">
        <key>foo</key>
        <value>this is foo.</value>
    </data>
    <data type="string">
        <key>bar</key>
        <value>this is bar from velocity.</value>
    </data>
    <tool>
        <key>map</key>
        <scope>session</scope>
        <class>java.util.HashMap</class>
    </tool>
    <tool>
        <key>date</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DateTool</class>
    </tool>
</toolbox>
```

velocity.properties

```
webapp.resource.loader.path=/WEB-INF/templates/
```

...and a simple index.vm (which for example if you notice on the tutorial website has an incorect closing html tag)

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>My text is :  $serv.getMessage() </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Files structure on the left:
[image: myStructure]

Sorry for the long post, any help would be apreciated!

Comment: have you tried removing the trailing space in your web.xml after org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet ?

Comment: @Jako I tried now, sadly it didn't fix the problem :(, but thankyou for your reply. I will edit the code in this post too.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems to find your libraries.

I would try moving the velocity libraries into your WEB-INF/lib folder, so that they are deployed on the server with your application, or try to add the velocity libraries in the lib folder of your tomcat server.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "moving the velocity libraries" ? like literaly copyng the 2 velocity and other 2 velocity tools jars from their paths into WEB-INF/lib folder and adding them again to the project in Eclipse or? (as I mentioned, I am new to all this)

Comment: Yes, I would copy the files into WEB-INF /lib, and then update the reference in my project (right click>properties>Java build path).

Comment: I tryed doing an entirely new project this time a bit different but with mostly the same core, result is same error as in the screenshot, I officialy quit this ****. If someone knows the correct answer to the problem feel free to write it!

Comment: I have noticed that getting a simple velocity project to run through eclipse is having the same effect on me. please let us know if you got this working. stuck on the same problem and cannot get bothered to look at velocity anymore. it would be nice if there is at least one tutorial for velocity in eclipse.

Comment: hey, sorry but as I said above I just quit trying, this was not so important, just as an extra to an assignment I had at that time.